# Create a 2D Heatmap in Java for Android with data from a Matrix and a spezific Color Gradient

Tags: java, android, heatmap

I am trying to create a `HeatMap` witch is displayed in an `ImageView` in my `Android` application.

I get the data as an `.csv` file and write it to an multidimensional `array`.
The `Array` contains data (0 to 499)for each `Pixel` of a 100x400 Image.
I created an `java` class to get a colour gradient array from 5 colours and get back an `(int) Array[500]` with the sRGB colors.
Now I am stuck on how to create a `Bitmap` (or something like that) with the data and the corresponding Colour from the `Array`.
Tried to understand the GoogleMaps `Heatmap` example and other ones but have no clue yet.
I am sorry if I asked an existing Question, but i have found nothing helpful yet. The code below is written in java and works with java libs (like java.awt.image.BufferedImage) witch are not accessible for Android.
dataColorIndices is an 100x400 `Array` witch contains the specific indice for the colour `Array` of each pixel in Data and is created in another method.

```
private void drawData() 
{
    bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(data.length,data[0].length, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    bufferedGraphics = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
    
    for (int x = 0; x < data.length; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < data[0].length; y++)
        {
            bufferedGraphics.setColor(colors[dataColorIndices[x][y]]);
            bufferedGraphics.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
        }
    }
    try {
        File outputfile = new File("C:/.../HeatMap.png");
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", outputfile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception;
    }
}
```

The Code is written by Matthew Beckler (https://www.mbeckler.org/heatMap/).

Comment: It would be helpful to post some code for us to see what you have already or what you have tried

Comment: Would it be easier to use a library like JFreeChart? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739422/heatmaps-with-jfreechart